# Custom Spring scope based on constructor args

Tags: java, spring

I need to define a custom scope where given a constructor argument same bean instance is used when the arg is the same.

But, the objectFactory parameter doesn't give access to the constructor arguments.

```
    @Override
    public Object get(String name, ObjectFactory<?> objectFactory) {

        // This method doesn't exists. It's what I need
        String arg = (String) objectFactory.getArg(1);

        if (!mScopedObjects.containsKey(arg)) {

            mScopedObjects.put(arg, objectFactory.getObject());
        }

        return mScopedObjects.get(arg);
    }


//Configuration
@Bean
@Scope("myscope")
public Foo getFoo(String fooId) {

    return new Foo(fooId);
}

//Somewhere in the project
Foo one = context.getBean(Foo.class, "one");
Foo two = context.getBean(Foo.class, "two");
Foo bar = context.getBean(Foo.class, "one");
```

"one" and "bar" should be same instance, "two" another instance.

Other solutions states to use a FactoryBean class. But I need a custom scope.

Any solution?